# How can I reduce the memory usage of a tiny MEMORY table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After running the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE mem_test (i int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=MEMORY;
INSERT INTO mem_test () VALUES ();
SELECT table_rows,avg_row_length,data_length,index_length FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='mem_test';
```

I get this in MySQL 5.7.28:

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| table_rows | avg_row_length | data_length | index_length |
+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
|          1 |              8 |      126992 |       126984 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

and this in MariaDB 10.4.10:

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| table_rows | avg_row_length | data_length | index_length |
+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
|          1 |              5 |     1677712 |      2093064 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

My table will never grow anywhere close to the size of these pre-allocated buffers, so how can I get MySQL and MariaDB to waste less RAM?  Or aren't they actually using what this query indicates??

Additional comparisons, for reference:

```
+-------+--------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| DB    | Engine | table_rows | avg_row_length | data_length | index_length |
+-------+--------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| MySQL | MEMORY |          1 |              8 |      126992 |       126984 |
| Maria | MEMORY |          1 |              5 |     1677712 |      2093064 |
| Both  | InnoDB |          1 |          16384 |       16384 |            0 |
| Both  | MyISAM |          1 |              7 |           7 |         2048 |
+-------+--------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I found a note on the MySQL forums that "memory tables grow by 'read_buffer_size' bytes when they need extending" (https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?92,405702,417606#msg-417606), but my numbers don't agree: I have `read_buffer_size = 131072` in MySQL and `2097152` in MariaDB.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%heap%';`

Comment: Hmmm... I got  1 |              8 |     2093072 |      2093072 | on 5.6.22.

Comment: I get 1 | 5 | 126992 | 126984 | with 10.4.11 using default settings, so similar to what is reported in the question for 5.7.28.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%heap%';` gives me `max_heap_table_size` = `16777216` (MySQL) or `33554432` (MariaDB), and no other variables.

Comment: I got `|  1 |   8 | 61456 | 61464 |` on 8.0.18.  When leaving out the `AUTO INCREMENT` the data_length and index_length are dropping to 0.

Comment: @Luuk - I only get 0 for both sizes /before/ the `INSERT` query.

Comment: @RogerDueck: I must have missed the failed insert because of a missing default value for `i`.

Comment: @RogerDueck It looks like your MariaDB 'read_buffer_size' should be removed from the configuration to allow defaults to work for you, shutdown; restart and redo your tests to see if you achieve your goal of lowering the RAM required for the MEMORY table.

Answer (score 1):

Although `data_length` and `index_length` aren't exact multiples of `read_buffer_size`, they **are** based on it.  So adjusting `read_buffer_size` in my.cnf **is** the solution (thanks @Wilson Hauck), as Shane Bester pointed out on the MySQL forums:

> memory tables grow by 'read_buffer_size' bytes when they need extending (https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?92,405702,417606#msg-417606)

Based on performance tests by Peter Zaitsev in 2007 (https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/09/17/mysql-what-read_buffer_size-value-is-optimal/), the default 128K setting is generally best, and using smaller values brings very little penalty.

Comment: Roger, thanks for digging deeper than most of us would for the CAUSE of this use of RAM.  Caution, if Handler_read_next Rate Per Second increases significantly, you may have an edge case that can benefit from larger read_buffer_size (double it, and monitor RPS and general response time).

Comment: How do I get `handler_read_next` rate per second? By running `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'handler_read_next'` regularly and tracking the rate of change? Is there a general range of values that would be considered ideal?

Comment: Yes, divide the result by uptime (seconds) for RPS.  View my profile, Network profile for contact info and consider our free download from Utility Scripts the globalstatusage10sec.sql that will calculate the rate at the end of 10 seconds for you.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.